# Why can't I log in into Alfresco after deploying an AMP?

Tags: alfresco

I installed Alfresco in the Google cloud. Thereafter I was able log in as administrator (on `http://AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD/share/page/`). 
Then I

1. built [this project](https://bitbucket.org/altruix/anote/src) using `mvn clean package -DskipTests=true`,
2. uploaded the resulting file `anote-1.0-SNAPSHOT.amp` to `/opt/bitnami/apps/alfresco/amps` on the server,
3. ran `sudo ./apply_amps.sh` in `/opt/bitnami/apps/alfresco`, and
4. re-started the server.

Thereafter the login page (`http://AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD/share/page/`) stopped to work. Whenever I enter my admin credentials I get the error `Your authentication details haven't been recognized or Alfresco Content Services may not be available at this time.`

How can I fix this error (make sure that I can log in into the admin page again)?

**Notes**

- When I log in on `http://AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD/share/page/` I use the credentials provided by Bitnami:

[image: Credentials]

- I looked at the log file `/opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/logs` and found the error below there. I believe I have fixed this errot, but after deploying a corrected AMP file and re-booting the machine, I still cannot log into Alfresco.

  Caused by: org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespaceException: Namespace prefix anote is not mapped to a namespace URI
      at org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName.createQName(QName.java:109)
      at org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName.createQName(QName.java:131)
      at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.M2ClassDefinition.(M2ClassDefinition.java:114)
      at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.M2TypeDefinition.(M2TypeDefinition.java:49)
      at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.CompiledModel.constructDefinitions(CompiledModel.java:167)
      at org.alfresco.repo.dictionary.CompiledModel.(CompiledModel.java:106)
      ... 38 more

Comment: When you're getting login errors to share, it's best to switch over and try to log into /alfresco/ - that'll let you easily check if the repo is up and working or not

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error by [changing](https://bitbucket.org/altruix/anote/commits/ba533582dd6c3ca536ecff37553bbfda0baf668a) the version number of the model. It looks like the faulty model was not updated (hence the Alfresco WAR could not be deployed), until I changed the version.